Specifying Item Spacing in UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration
Currently, I am using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout to achieve the following list layout with spacing:

We were thinking of trying out UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration due to its ability to support swipe actions.
We would like to specify the spacing between each item. However, I do not find a way to specify item spacing in UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration.
Does UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration not support item spacing, or have I missed something?
Thanks.

The list layout is basically intended to simulate (or perhaps even replace) a table view. So the way to get the spacing you're after is the same as what you would do to get that sort of spacing with a table view: draw the colored rectanges with a vertical inset, top and bottom, from the actual cell. The cell itself is transparent, so the effect is the same.

Thanks. Will try such a concept but not sure whether there will be any glitches. For instance, touching the space region shouldn't trigger touch event. But, such a workaround might...
